# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2\left(n\right)}{n}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

The harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\frac 1 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots$ is divergent.

Since $ \frac1n = \frac{\sin^2\left(n\right)}{n} + \frac{\cos^2\left(n\right)}{n}$.  I'm wondering if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2\left(n\right)}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2\left(n\right)}{n}$ are divergent.

Here is my try:

\begin{align*}
\cos 2n &= 2 \cos^2 n - 1 \\
  &= 1 - 2 \sin^2 n
\\
\\
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2\left(n\right)}{n} &=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\sin^2\left(n\right)}{2n} \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 - \cos 2n}{2n} \\
\\
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos^2\left(n\right)}{n} &=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\cos^2\left(n\right)}{2n} \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1 + \cos 2n}{2n}
\end{align*}

How should I proceed?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28n%3D1%2Cinfinity%2Ccos%5E2%28n%29%2Fn%29) gives a quite complicated result, the sum seems to converge.